# Python. Конвертировать кодировку в раскодированный текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Ситуация требует кодировать и декодировать текст, записанный, например, в 'utf-16' кодировке путём написания декодируемого текста в input

Результат программы должен выглядеть так:

```
Ваш текст: b'\xff\xfeB\x04'

Раскодированный текст: т
```

Код сейчас:

```py
input_txt = input('Ваш текст: ')
x = input_txt.decode()
y = x.decode(encoding='utf-16',errors='ignore')
print('\nРаскодированный текст: ' + str(y))
```

К сожалению, это не работает корректно

Comment: `x = input_txt.decode(encoding='utf-16')`. decode как encode, если не указывать encoding, использует системную

Comment: Вылезает данная ошибка :/ `Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: `x = input_txt.encode(encoding='utf-16')`, тогда в `x` будут байты в `utf-16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вводе `b'\xff\xfeB\x04'` через `input` фактически получается такая строка: `"b'\\xff\\xfeB\\x04'"`. Перед декодированием ее нужно разобрать ее как литерал (т.е. перевести в набор байт `b'\xff\xfeB\x04'` в данном случае). Для этого можно использовать функцию [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

input_txt = input('Ваш текст: ')
print(repr(input_txt))  # "b'\\xff\\xfeB\\x04'"
x = ast.literal_eval(input_txt)
print(repr(x))  # b'\xff\xfeB\x04'
y = x.decode(encoding='utf-16',errors='ignore')
print('\nРаскодированный текст: ' + y)
```